# magnific popup: open by clicking on something other than the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Client has requested that the image caption completely cover the thumbnail on hover, so I now need to be able to click the caption to open Magnific Popup instead of the `<a>`. So far I have been able to do:

**JS/jQuery:**

```
jQuery(".caption").on("click", function(event) {
  var items = [];
  jQuery(".item").each(function() {
    items.push( {
      src: jQuery(this).find("a").first().attr("href")
    } );
  });
  jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    items: items,
    image: {
      titleSrc: function(item) {
        console.log( item.el );
        // return item.el.clone();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

See the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uusLmpkd/2/)** for an example, and the HTML and CSS (plus alternative JS that doesn't work either).

It's giving me two blockers:

1. It's always the first image that pops up, instead of the image that one clicked on.
2. That part about `return item.el.clone();` is commented out because it's producing an "item.el is undefined" error (which doesn't seem to happen when magnificPopup is instantiated via `jQuery('.caption').magnificPopup()` as opposed to `jQuery.magnificPopup.open()`). However, I need the caption HTML to show up in the popup as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an array of items you can pass the index of the first item you want to show. So I have used `var index = jQuery(this).parent().index()` to get the index of the current clicked item and then passed that variable in to the `magnificPopup` function.

To get the caption in the popup I have added an extra property to the items object called `titleSrc`, which you can then retreive in the `titleSrc` option using `item.data.titleSrc`.

https://jsfiddle.net/sjp7j1zx/4/

```
jQuery(".caption a").on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

jQuery(".caption").on("click", function(event) {
  var items = [];
  jQuery(".item").each(function() {
    // Pass an extra titleSrc property to the item object so we can use it in the magnificPopup function
    items.push( {
      src: jQuery(this).find("a").first().attr("href"),
      titleSrc: jQuery(this).find('.caption').html()
    } );
  });

  // Get the index of the current selected item
  var index = jQuery(this).parent().index();

  jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    items: items,
    image: {
      titleSrc: function(item) {
       // get the titleSrc from the data property of the item object that we defined in the .each loop
       return item.data.titleSrc;
      }
    }
    // Pass the current items index here to define which item in the array to show first
  }, index);
});
```

Comment: Wizard indeed. Thank you!